# Increment by 1 in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to count the rows in a DataList where id is 3 and put the value in a label.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Product.Items.Count; ++i)
{    
    if (table.Rows[i]["id"].ToString() == "3")
    {
        int x = x + 1;
        lblCounter.text = x.ToString
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `table` in your case ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int x = x + 1;
```

Will not work. You have to do something like

```
int x = 0;
```

before the loop and

```
x = x + 1;
```

inside it. Additionally, you might want to put `lblCounter.text = x.ToString` after the loop, so as to update it just once.

This makes

```cs
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Product.Items.Count; ++i)
  if (table.Rows[i]["id"].ToString() == "3")
    x = x + 1;
lblCounter.text = x.ToString();
```

Comment: @user1016253 - All Eugen did was "fix" the code so it would do what the author wants. If you have a better idea then post it as an answer.

Comment: @FelixK. I personally allways use i++. but I didn't change it here as to keep as much as possible of the OP's code intact

Comment: Or `lblCounter.Text = (++x).ToString();`

Answer (score 15):

```
lblCounter.Text = table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Count(row => row["id"] == 3).ToString();
```

Edited based on KooKiz's comment and assuming table is a `DataTable`.

Comment: I was too busy signaling the error for thinking about a better solution, +1 out of the box ^^

Comment: If it's a DataTable, he may need to add OfType: `table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Count(row => row["id"] == 3).ToString();`

Comment: Shouldn't it somewhere have `AsEnumerable` and also `Count` is a property unless i missed something

Comment: -1, I really doubt in that, someone who do not understand the basics, should use such sophisticated solution. Especially when is not commented. This answer is not a good solution of the problem.

Comment: +1 because these answers are for everyone, not just for the OP

Comment: @noah1989 now it fits the bill since it states the assumption

Comment: @Vash - So post your own solution.

Comment: @Ramhound, was posted long time ago.

Answer (score 5):

Move the declation of `x` to outer scope.

```
int x=0;
for (int i = 0; i < Product.Items.Count; ++i)
 if (table.Rows[i]["id"].ToString() == "3")
 {
      x = x + 1;
      lblCounter.text = x.ToString
 }
```

The improved one:

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Product.Items.Count; ++i)
   if (table.Rows[i]["id"].ToString() == "3")
      x = x + 1;
lblCounter.text = x.ToString
```

Comment: Do you mean the declaration of `x`?

Comment: also you can change `x = x + 1;` to `x += 1` or `x++;` for readability

Comment: @Jani - Why do you use **x=x+1;** instead of **x++;**?

Answer (score 5):

```
int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Product.Items.Count; ++i)
{
     if (table.Rows[i]["id"].ToString() == "3")
     {
       x++;
     }
}

lblCounter.Text = x.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have several problems in that code.

The reason you can not increment x varaible. Is that you declare it inside the loop. Because of that it is "recreated" for each run of loop.

Next issue might be that you are using the [preincrementation instead of post increment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators),the last thing is that generally is better to compare constant to variable. This protect you against unwanted NullPointerException.

So the improved code should look like:

```
int x = 0; //Declaration of x
for(int i=0; i< Product.Items.Count; i++) { //Post increment
 if("3".Equals(table.Rows[i]["id"]) { // Check constant against variable. 
    x++; // Post increment x = x + 1; 
 }  
}
lblCounte.Text = Convert.ToString(x); //Assign the int result to String member.
```

In case of any other questions do not hesitate to write them down.

Peace.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `x` outside the loop, then call `.ToString()` to find the string value. (That's a method, not a property, so it needs the final `()`.

Try this:

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Product.Items.Count; ++i)

   if (table.Rows[i]["id"].ToString() == "3")
   {
        x = x + 1;
        lblCounter.text = x.ToString();
   }
}
```

You can also use `x++` to increment in one step but personally I prefer to make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question.

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Product.Items.Count; ++i)

     if (table.Rows[i]["id"].ToString() == "3")
     {
          x = x + 1;
          lblCounter.text = x.ToString()
     }
```